# Swift error. Used undeclared type String

Tags: swift, undefined

if we insert line "case let dictionary as [String : AnyObject]:" inside struct's method everything works fine. But if use inside nested enums we get error "Used undefined type String"

```
public struct JSON {

    public enum Type : Int {

        case Number
        case String
        case Bool
        case Array
        case Dictionary
        case Null
        case Unknown

        public static func evaluate(object: AnyObject) -> Type {

            switch object {
            case let dictionary as [String : AnyObject]: // this lines supply error. Use of undefined type String
                return .Dictionary
            default:
                return .Unknown
            }
        }

    } // enum Type
```

Could some one explain why I have the error with String type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems `enum Type` contains `case String`, and it hides the `String` what you want. I tried the code in Playground and there is no more error after change `String` to another name.

**EDIT**
How about reading the project *SwiftyJSON* (only single file)

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift

I does very similar job.(JSON Handling)

It also contains the code looks like this:

```
public enum Type :Int {

    case Number
    case String
    case Bool
    case Array
    case Dictionary
    case Null
    case Unknown
}
```

I think this project will be very helpful for you.
(and I guess you may end up using this project)

Comment: Grate. Thanks. I was so inattentive. Shame on me.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this not changing String to another name?

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the other answer, `String` inside `enum Type` 
refers to the enumeration value. The same problem would occur with

```
let a : Array<Int> = []
let b : Bool = false
```

inside methods of `enum Type`. Renaming the enumeration values is probably the best solution.

But for the sake of completeness: You *can* solve the problem
by prepending the "Swift" module name explicitly to refer to the
`String` type:

```
case let dictionary as [Swift.String : AnyObject]:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix this without renaming the enum case, you can change the argument type to `Swift.String`, i.e.:

`case let dictionary as [Swift.String : AnyObject]:`

That should work (I had a similar problem and this solved it).

Comment: This solution was already provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263056/1974224)